# Can I upgrade from Windows 7 32 bit to Windows 7 64 bit without losing data?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I want to play Fallout 4 and I found out I need 64bit system in order to play it, but I have 32bit system and I'm capable of upgrading.

Can I reinstall Windows without losing pictures and that stuff if I put them in D:\files or something like that?

I don't want to buy more storage just to save my files.

I also don't want to use Google drive or similar because I have a lot of pictures on my PC.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to "in-place" upgrade 32-bit to 64-bit without doing a full reformat/reinstall of the drive. Saving your data on another partition of the drive won't work as well since the drive will be fully wiped and partitioned for the new OS.

Comment: You can do that easily provided your processor is of 64 bit architecture and you have enough space on your c: partition(~20 gb),you just have to reinstall windows from a 64 bit Windows 7 installation media just copy your required data of c: to some other partitions and on installation do custom installation and format your c: partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can I upgrade from Windows 7 32 bit to Windows 7 64 bit without losing data?

> If you want to move from a 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit
>   version of Windows 7 or vice versa, you'll need to **back up your
>   files** and choose the Custom option during Windows 7 installation.
>   Then, you'll need to restore your files and reinstall your programs.
>   For more information about performing a custom installation, see
>   [Installing and reinstalling Windows 7‍.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/installing-and-reinstalling-windows-7)
>
> Notes
>
> To install a 64-bit version of Windows 7 on a computer running a
>   32-bit version of Windows, you'll need to start, or boot, your
>   computer using a 64-bit Windows 7 installation disc or files.
>
> If you start your computer using a 64-bit Windows 7 installation disc
>   or files, but your computer isn't capable of running a 64-bit version
>   of Windows, you'll see a Windows Boot Manager error. You'll need to
>   use a 32-bit Windows 7 installation disc or files instead.

Source [32-bit and 64-bit Windows: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-7)